# Is it possible to see if AJAX was used just by looking at the HTTP traffic?

Tags: ajax, http, networking, http-headers

I am making a program to monitor my network, and in this program I am reading the HTTP traffic which is going through my network. One thing I want to do is to separate the AJAX HTTP traffic from the "normal" HTTP traffic. Is it possible to do such a thing? Is there maybe something in the HTTP headers that tells you if a request is an AJAX request?

Comment: A hackish solution would be to check for JSON and possibly XML responses.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `X-Requested-With` header that most frameworks set when making AJAX requests. It looks like this:

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

There are no guarantees (obviously the headers are under the client's complete control), but usually it's there.

Comment: I didn't know about the `X-Requested-With` header, but when I checked a simple AJAX request made with Firefox I couldn't find this header, so I'm not sure how trust-able this header is.

Comment: @Cokegod: Well, no header can ever be "trusted" because they are all set at the client's pleasure. *In practice*, all frameworks that I know of voluntarily set this header when making AJAX requests. But let's take your counter-example: you made the request, you inspected it. Was there anything in it that clearly flagged it as AJAX? Presumably not. So that's your trustable answer right there.

Comment: I am aware that I can never 100% trust a header, but you do have the `User-Agent` header, which is almost always used. I was hoping for something similar that shows if the request is sent through AJAX or not. I guess I will be using the `X-Requested-With` header if I won't find anything better.